# variable assigned is undefined angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have code as below. The constructor uses the router methods to get the previous route and sets a variable in it. Then `ngOnInit()` call a method which in turn calls another method to compare the variable saved through constructor with the list values from service.

At this point when comparing the variable that is stored in contructor is always coming as undefined. However, inside constructor the value og this.selBoard is 40. The value printed in console for `console.log(this.selBoard);` is always undefined.

Where am I going wrong? Even though its an sync call, the value is printed properly which is 40 in the constructor so there is no way its value is undefined inside getRouterDetails()

```
//...
selBoard : number;
selectedBoard : Board= new Board();

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
        .subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
            var url = events[0].urlAfterRedirects;
            var urlIndex = url.indexOf('boardId=');
            var boardId = url.substring(urlIndex+8, urlIndex+10);
            this.selBoard = Number(boardId);
            console.log('selBoard --- '+this.selBoard);
        });
            
    ngOnInit(): void {
    //..
    if (this.loggedInUser.isAdmin)  {
        this.loadBoardsList();}
    ..//
    }
    
    
    loadBoardsList() { 
            this._boardService.loadBoards().subscribe( posts => {
                this.data = posts; 
                console.log('loadBoardsList', this.data);
            },
            error => { 
                console.log('loadBoardsList - error',error);
               // this._errorService.handleError(error); 
                this._messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Error Message', detail:error.error+' - '+error.message, sticky: true}); 
            }, 
            () => {  
                this.boardsList = this.data.boardLi; 
                this.getRouterDetails();
                console.log(this.selectedBoard);
            });  
    }
    
    getRouterDetails() {
       for (let i = 0; i < this.boardsList.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.boardsList[i].id);
            console.log(this.selBoard);
            if (this.boardsList[i].id == this.selBoard) {
                console.log('Which one selected ---'+this.selBoard);
                this.selectedBoard = this.boardsList[i];
            }
        }
     }
```

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be doing an extremely complicated way of getting param values. why not just use this.route.queryParams?

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.boardId = params.boardId;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I am not getitng the current url. I am getting the previous url, and that is the way it works. If you have an easy way to get the previous route then please let me know. Eg . I click A, when i click B i should get the link of A.

Comment: hmm, I guess I still don't understand. If you have access to the boardId on A, why not just pass that through as a param when you click B?

Comment: ok this is how my page is. Assume A,B,C as parent menu and when I click A I see x,y,z pages . So from A , boardId is passed as a param. When I am in z for example and when I click A now, I want to retain the boardId . When I am in x or y or z and click on B or C boardId should be nullified. One way is to identify the previous route and if it is x or y or z then get boardId else null. This is however passed as router navigate with param values. Child pages get the param. When I click the parent link I am trying to get from the url. Please correct me the best way if u feel otherwise.

Comment: its hard to tell exactly what you are doing, but my guess is you can accomplish what you want by having 2 variables. boardId and parentBoardId and pass them both through to every view. so in your example set them both to the same value when you click A. then if you are in x and click B nullify boardId but pass parentBoardId. That way you always have your parentBoardId and never have to go looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that `.subscribe` is asynchronous and if the `.subscribe` inside of the `ngOnInit (loadBoardList())` happens before the `.subscribe` of the constructor, then you will face this race condition (property being undefined somewhere, and populated elsewhere). It seems like these subscriptions rely on each other and for this I would use `switchMap`.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
selBoard : number;
selectedBoard : Board= new Board();

    constructor(private router: Router){
      // get rid of the code inside of the constructor
    }
            
    ngOnInit(): void {
    //..
    if(this.loggedInUser.isAdmin)  {
        this.loadBoardsList();}
    ..//
    }
    
    
    loadBoardsList(){
        this.router.events.pipe(
            filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), 
            pairwise(),
            switchMap((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
               var url = events[0].urlAfterRedirects;
               var urlIndex = url.indexOf('boardId=');
               var boardId = url.substring(urlIndex+8, urlIndex+10);
               this.selBoard = Number(boardId);
               console.log('selBoard --- '+this.selBoard);
               return this._boardService.loadBoards(); // switch to this observable now, once the previous is done
            }),    
        ).subscribe( posts =>{
                this.data = posts; 
                console.log('loadBoardsList',this.data);
                },
                error => { 
                console.log('loadBoardsList - error',error);
               // this._errorService.handleError(error); 
                this._messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Error Message', detail:error.error+' - '+error.message, sticky: true}); 
                }, 
                () => {  
                this.boardsList = this.data.boardLi; 
                this.getRouterDetails();
                console.log(this.selectedBoard);
            });  
    }
    
    getRouterDetails(){
       for (let i = 0; i < this.boardsList.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.boardsList[i].id);
            console.log(this.selBoard);
            if(this.boardsList[i].id == this.selBoard){
                console.log('Which one selected ---'+this.selBoard);
                this.selectedBoard = this.boardsList[i];
            }
        }
     }
```